# "sed delete" command in bash not always work

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, linux-mint

With the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'if [ -f /etc/skel/.bashrc ]; then . /etc/skel/.bashrc; fi' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'enable -n echo' >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias cls=\"echo -en '\033c\033[3J'\"" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias cmdlist='compgen -c | sort -b'" >> ~/.bashrc
sed -i '/if [ -f /etc/skel/.bashrc ]; then . /etc/skel/.bashrc; fi/d' ~/.bashrc
sed -i '/enable -n echo/d' ~/.bashrc
sed -i "/alias cls=\"echo -en '\033c\033[3J'\"/d" ~/.bashrc
sed -i "/alias cmdlist='compgen -c | sort -b'/d" ~/.bashrc
```

I expect an empty file .bashrc, instead it contains:

```
if [ -f /etc/skel/.bashrc ]; then . /etc/skel/.bashrc; fi
alias cls="echo -en '\033c\033[3J'"
```

Why?

Comment: Square parenthesis (`[` and `]`) have meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: the escape \\[ desn't work.

Comment: Hahaha! Are you sure? Or you are hitting a different problem? Your regex have more problems than that, like the slashes inside the regex. They tell where the expression finishes, and you are telling `sed` that it is finishing after `if -f `. More things to be escaped!

Comment: Thank you, after 34 mins, i have solved it!

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it thanks to Poshi!

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'if [ -f /etc/skel/.bashrc ]; then . /etc/skel/.bashrc; fi' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'enable -n echo' >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias cls=\"echo -en '\033c\033[3J'\"" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "alias cmdlist='compgen -c | sort -b'" >> ~/.bashrc
sed -i '/if \[ -f \/etc\/skel\/.bashrc \]; then . \/etc\/skel\/.bashrc; fi/d' ~/.bashrc
sed -i '/enable -n echo/d' ~/.bashrc
sed -i "/alias cls=\"echo -en '\\\033c\\\033\[3J'\"/d" ~/.bashrc
sed -i "/alias cmdlist='compgen -c | sort -b'/d" ~/.bashrc
```